# Unmatched quotation mark SAS

Tags: sas

```
%macro name_modal();
/*Create macro variables which contain the modalities of variables*/
%do i=1 %to &num_Var;
    data _null_;
        set  &lib..Table_variable_modal_&i.;
        call symputx('num_Mod'||compress(put(&i,4.)),_N_,"G");
        call symputx('table'||compress(put(&i,4.))||'modal'||compress(put(_N_,4.)),compress(&&name_Var&i.),"G");
    run;

%end;

/*Display modalities by variable*/
%do i=1 %to &num_Var;
    %put &&name_Var&i. has &&num_Mod&i. modalities ;
    %do j=1 %to &&num_Mod&i.;
        %put %nrstr(&&tableb&i.modal&j.);
    %end;
%end;
%mend name_modal;
%name_modal();
```

I hope the code is self-documenting.
I'll explain the problems here. 
Everything is working fine until I pass to the second of the program which serves to display the modalities by variables.

For example when the name of modalities being stocked in the macro variables are like
$100% BLO,
100% COLOR,
AVON & RAGOBERT,
BALLANTINE'S,
L'OREAL,
AT&T,
U-V-A
etc
I fail to use %put properly.
I've tried using %bquote and %nrstr, but the problem persists.
So far, the only solution I can see is to modify the name of the modalities but since the names come from a client, I don't have the possibility to make amendment on the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a few times, I find `%superq` could solve this problem. Handling special characters in macro is troublesome. This [page](http://www.okstate.edu/sas/v8/sashtml/macro/z1061345.htm) provides some useful tips on macro quoting.

I simplified your code here to the following

UPDATE: make it double-loop case.

```
data test;
 input name ~ &  $15.;
 datalines;
 100% BLO
 100% COLOR
 AVON & RAGOBERT
 BALLANTINE'S
 L'OREAL
 AT&T
 U-V-A
 ;
run;

%macro name_modal();
/*Create macro variables which contain the modalities of variables*/
%do i=1 %to 4;
    data _null_;
     set  test;
     call symputx('num_Mod1',_N_,"G");
     call symputx('tableb'||compress(put(&i,4.))||'modal'||compress(put(_N_,4.)),name,"G");
    run;
%end;

   %do i=1 %to 4;
    %do j=1 %to 7;
        %put %superq(tableb&i.modal&j);
    %end;
   %end;
%mend name_modal;
%name_modal();
```

The result will display correctly.

Note that it is `%superq(tableb&i.modal&j)` not `%superq(&&tableb&i.modal&j)` as `superq` accepts macro variable name without extra ampersand.

Comment: Curiously this works. I'm saying so because I remembered having used %superq but I still got some errors. I'll give you feedbacks when I got to try to debug the program again at work tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: I've just got to debug the program. The program went well when I only loop on the modalities(j=1 to numMod). So far, %superq() is able to its job. However, when I try to add another loop to this, meaning(i=1 to numVar), %superq() fails to interpret %&&tableb&i.modal&j.  correctly.

Comment: I think it's because of the double ampersand that %superq fails

Comment: @afiqjohari use `%superq(tableb&i.modal&j)` not `%superq(&&tableb&i.modal&j)`. I modified the code a bit to include double loop. see http://pastebin.com/2F3q0iLs

Comment: It did work! What a relieve. But know it begs a question, how %superq(tableb&i.modal&j) and %superq(&&tableb&i.modal&j) are processed by macro SAS? 
Anyway, you just saved me a lot of time. Thank you very much!

Comment: @afiqjohari By stating `&&tableb&i.modal&j` you are actually requesting the value of macro variable `tableb&i.modal&j`. That's the difference. In your case, special characters don't interrupt macro variable name resolution but value resolution. That's why you get error when stating `&&tableb&i.modal&j`

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer the question for all your sample data because I can't recreate your code (missing global macros).

**[UPDATE]** It is more difficult to get macros to resolve which include characters that need to be masked. Post some code that can be executed, and more help can be provided.

[Here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001061290.htm) is a good link for macro quoting.

[This](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/forum2007/152-2007.pdf) has a really good diagram detailing which macro masking functions to use for different situations.

%Str will work even if a % or & are included in the string, as long as they are followed by a space. %NRSTR if either could be interpreted as a macro variable or macro call.
You can precede a single quote (') or single double quote (") with a percent sign (%), or use BQUOTE or NRBQUOTE (if your character string includes & or %).

Here is a start **[UPDATE]**:

```
%Macro Test(var=);
 %Put &var;
%Mend test;

%Test(Var=%str($100% BLO)) ;

%Test(Var=%str(100% COLOR)) ;
%Test(Var=%nrstr(100 %COLOR)) ;

%Test(Var=%str(AVON & RAGOBERT)) ;
%Test(Var=%nrstr(AVON &RAGOBERT)) ;

%Test(Var=%str(BALLANTINE%'S)) ;
%Test(Var=%bquote(BALLANTINE'S)) ;

%Test(Var=%str(L%'OREAL)) ;
%Test(Var=%bquote(L'OREAL)) ;

%Test(Var=%nrstr(AT&T)) ;
%Test(Var=%str(U-V-A)) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I'm currently not at work, so it'd be harder for me to give you the necessary global macros to recreate the code.
By the way, normally your %Test should be working well except that, in my case, I couldn't modify the names of variable modalities like L'OREAL to L%'OREAL.